# django: admin.StackedInline show full name instead of user name

Tags: django, django-admin

my inline:

```
class CollaboratorInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Collaborator
    extra = 0
```

my model:

```
class Collaborator(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    collaborator = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'groups__name':u'team1'})
    def reutnName(self):
        return self.collaborator.get_full_name()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.collaborator.get_full_name()
```

The inline collaborator is shown as a drop downlist, and the ppl are shown as usernames intead of full names. 
does anyone know how to change it to full name?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it using formfield_for_manytomany and formfield_for_foreignkey
i thought they could only be used in modeladmin, but it could also be used for StackedInline 
:)